# Android Studio: how to increase the speed and performance of it

Tags: android-intent

i'm having machine with 4GB ram present in it. im new to andriod studio but when to try to run even a sample program, it is taking so much time. is there any way we can increase the performance of this toolkit. Please advise thanks.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. WIthout seeing any code, the code of a bottleneck you have identified for example... well without it, it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run your app on the real device. If you don't have the real device make sure you have installed 
[Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

One more link that can help you..
[Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)